# Не срабатывает условие в скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При изменении значения `location` в заданном диапазоне, требуется выполнить условие, нo условие не срабатывает. Значение `location` - это бегунок `JQuery UI`. При передвижении бегунка, соответственно, меняется значение `location`, о чем говорит изменение значения в консоли, но условие не срабатывает.

```js
var el, location;
$("#slider").change(function() {
  el = $(this);
  location = el.val();
  console.log(location);
  if (location > 9 && location < 100) {
    console.log("Условие сработало");
  }
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fifty">
  <img src="../img/circle_small.png" alt="">
  <p id="output">100</p>
</div>
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `location` скорее всего имеет тип строка а Вы сравниваете с цифрами

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Не вижу очевидных вещей.

Comment: Не за что, практикуйтесь побольше и такие вещи не будете упускать